# Popular Online Analytical Processing (OLAP) software

Tags: olap

Can you recommend some popular software to implement OLAP? It will be much better if there are extra related links.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that product recommendation questions are off-topic; they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main categories of the [OLAP systems - MOLAP and ROLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing):

- **MOLAP (multi-dimensional online analytical processing)** = MOLAP stores this data in an optimized multi-dimensional storage. The word optimized is important here. Data needs to be pre-processed to be stored in such special data stores but then reading of a data is fast (stored data is optimized for performing analytical queries).
- **ROLAP (relational online analytical processing)** = ROLAP does not require the pre-computation of analytical information. ROLAP store and access the data in a relational database and generate SQL queries to obtain analytical information (aggregate information is not pre-computed, but the information can be cached after computed for a first time).

OLAP systems consist of cubes, dimensions and measures. The cube metadata is typically created from a star schema or snowflake schema. I recommend to take a look at [The Data Warehouse Toolkit, 3rd Edition](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/books/data-warehouse-dw-toolkit/)

Basic **BI solutions** usually consist of five parts. I will describe them on open source **ROLAP solution** which I can recommend:

- **Source systems =** Various databases, web services, files. Objects for analysis. Data loaded to DWH.
- **OLAP DWH (data warehouse) =** Database for storing current and historical analytical data in multi-dimensional schemas (usually star schemas). For the ROLAP you can choose any RDBMS:

  - Row oriented: [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), etc.
  - Column oriented (optimal for OLAP): [Monet DB](https://www.monetdb.org/Home), [Vertica](http://www.vertica.com/), [Amazon Redshift](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/)
- **ETL (Extract-transform-load) =** Process of extracting data from source systems, transforming it and loading to DWH.

  - E.g. [Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/)
- **OLAP server =** Builds OLAP (cubes), on the top of DWH, which can be queried using multidimensional query language (MDX) and accessed by BI front-end applications.

  - There is an open source ROLAP server called [Mondrian OLAP](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/mondrian/) - cashes MDX results (use [OLAP schema workbench tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mondrian/files/schema%20workbench/) to create Mondrian OLAP schema).
- **BI Analysis tool =** Front-end application for analyzing data:

  - Ad-hoc analysis: [Saiku Analysis application](http://community.meteorite.bi/?cedownload) (you can preview [Saiku demo here](http://demo.saikuanalytics.com/))
  - Reporting, Dashboards: [Pentaho BI server CE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/) ([CDF](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/cdf/): charts portfolio [CCC](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/ccc/) + maps, etc.)

MOLAP solutions:

- There is an open source MOLAP server: [Palo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/palo/). Most of the others are commercial: [Jedox](http://www.jedox.com/en/), [icCube](http://www.iccube.com/), etc.

Other ROLAP solutions:

- [Microsoft Analysis Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/solutions/business-intelligence/analysis.aspx) (all aggregated OLAP data are precalculated within a step called *building OLAP*), [Oracle Business Intelligence Suite EE](http://www.oracle.com/us/solutions/business-analytics/business-intelligence/enterprise-edition/overview/index.html), etc.

Comment: Jedox is not an open source solution!